# Java - Changing the Menu Bar and Item Background and Text Color

Tags: java, menu, uimanager

How to change the Menu Bar and Item Color using `UIManager.put(key, value);`.

I have tried this method:

```
try {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", Color.black);
    UIManager.put("MenuBar.foreground", Color.white);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.black);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.foreground", Color.white);

    new Window();

}
catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

It doesn't work, then I remove the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`, then it will now work, but I need to stick to the original Operating System Look and Feel.

So how do I change the color of a Menu Bar and Item without using the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.CYAN);
  UIManager.put("MenuItem.opaque", true);
```

Comment: 1. Do you really need `opaque`? 2. How about the font color/foreground? Is my example great?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have my third year exams when you answered, which the question is not in my exams, just I have a project.

Comment: The opaque option must be used to take the color defined in the UIManager

Comment: I've tested it, and it worked, but how about the JMenuBar?